# Need help in regexp_substr and regexp_like

Tags: oracle10g

I have data like below in once column(having 5 records)

```
Failed to process Batch task. An exception occured while building Bond(00010068, BOND, CLOSE, ICT, TOK, EOD, Bond_EOD): You are trying to get DBond that doesn't exist. (DeliveryCount=2)
Failed to process Batch task. An exception occured while building Bond(00010068, BOND, CLOSE, ICT, TOK, EOD, Bond_EOD): You are trying to get DBond that doesn't exist. (DeliveryCount=0)
Failed to process Batch task. There was an error generating the XML document. (DeliveryCount=0)
Failed to process Batch task. There was an error generating the XML document. (DeliveryCount=0)
Failed to process Batch task. There was an error generating the XML document. (DeliveryCount=0)
```

Here i need to get the data like ( need data which is eclosed in () )

```
00010068, BOND, CLOSE, ICT, TOK, EOD, Bond_EOD
00010068, BOND, CLOSE, ICT, TOK, EOD, Bond_EOD
```

and i don't want to other that above mentioned data.

apart from that have to split the row data into columns like

```
col1        col2    col3        col4    col5        col6    col7
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
00010068    BOND    CLOSE       ICT      TOK        EOD     Bond_EOD
```

Can you please some on help me on this

Answer (score 0):

```
with tab as
(select 'Failed to process Batch task. An exception occured while building Bond(00010068, BOND, CLOSE, ICT, TOK, EOD, Bond_EOD): You are trying to get DBond that doesn''t exist. (DeliveryCount=2)' s from dual
union all select 'Failed to process Batch task. An exception occured while building Bond(00010068, BOND, CLOSE, ICT, TOK, EOD, Bond_EOD): You are trying to get DBond that doesn''t exist. (DeliveryCount=0)' from dual
union all select 'Failed to process Batch task. There was an error generating the XML document. (DeliveryCount=0)' from dual
union all select 'Failed to process Batch task. There was an error generating the XML document. (DeliveryCount=0)' from dual
union all select 'Failed to process Batch task. There was an error generating the XML document. (DeliveryCount=0)' from dual
)
select   trim(regexp_substr(parsed, '[^,]+', 1, 1)) col1
       , trim(regexp_substr(parsed, '[^,]+', 1, 2)) col2
       , trim(regexp_substr(parsed, '[^,]+', 1, 3)) col3
       , trim(regexp_substr(parsed, '[^,]+', 1, 4)) col4
       , trim(regexp_substr(parsed, '[^,]+', 1, 5)) col5
       , trim(regexp_substr(parsed, '[^,]+', 1, 6)) col6
       , trim(regexp_substr(parsed, '[^,]+', 1, 7)) col7
from
(
  select substr(regexp_substr(s, 'bond\([^)]+', 1, 1, 'i'), 6) parsed
  from tab where regexp_like(s, 'bond\(.+?\)', 'i')
);
```

`regexp_like(s, 'bond\(.+?\)', 'i')` returns true if a string **s** contains "bond(...)", case insensitive ("i" flag); `.+?` is a nongreedy at least one symbol - anything until the first ")"

`substr(regexp_substr(s, 'bond\([^)]+', 1, 1, 'i'), 6)` - get only the desired substring (... from "bond(...)"). Oracle10g doesn't support subexpressions so we have to make do with common substr to cut "bond("

Finally, get Nth "none-comma" sequence from the parsed string

Comment: Thanq will check this